# twitter bootstrap navbar isn't exandable

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I copy / pasted the example from http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar into this URL:

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/scripts/demo/bootstrap-nav.html

...and it's not working as I'd expect.

So if you shrink the browser width past a certain point the horizontal menu gets replaced with a button that, if clicked on, shows a vertical menu. At least that's my understanding of how it's supposed to work. But in the above example that is not how it works. The button appears but nothing happens when I click on it.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery ` You didn't add Jquery in the scripts. Bootstrap relies on its own scripts, plus the use of Jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look to the browser console (i.e. Firebug): you'll find there an exception

> Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery